# django: iregex is case sensitive

Tags: mysql, regex, django

Hitting the db (MySQL) with these two queries one right after another I get different results:

```
test1 = Agreement.objects.filter(pk=152, company__iregex='СитиСтро(и|й)')
test2 = Agreement.objects.filter(pk=152, company__iregex='ситистро(и|й)')

test1 <QuerySet [<Agreement: Agreement object>]>
test2 <QuerySet []>
```

with the actual value if the field ' "СитиСтрой" '

Now i'm pretty sure that is Cyrillics that is messing things up, because with records in Latin alphabet it works fine, but I have no idea how to go around that (bug?). Any advice here?

PS I did double check, there is no confusion here with similar looking C letters of English and Russian, but with different letter codes.

**Update:**
Checked the sql that Django sends to Mysql.

```
('SELECT `dbbs_app_agreement`.`id`, `dbbs_app_agreement`.`company`, '
 'FROM `dbbs_app_agreement` WHERE (`dbbs_app_agreement`.`company` REGEXP '
 'СитиСтро(и|й) AND `dbbs_app_agreement`.`id` = 152)')
```

Seems fine. 
Tried querying the table directly from phpmyadmin with

```
SELECT `dbbs_app_agreement`.`id`, `dbbs_app_agreement`.`company` FROM `dbbs_app_agreement` WHERE (`dbbs_app_agreement`.`id` = 152 AND `dbbs_app_agreement`.`company` REGEXP 'С')
```

which worked, but

```
SELECT `dbbs_app_agreement`.`id`, `dbbs_app_agreement`.`company` FROM `dbbs_app_agreement` WHERE (`dbbs_app_agreement`.`id` = 152 AND `dbbs_app_agreement`.`company` REGEXP 'с')
```

at the same time does not.

As @AndreyShipilov below offered, made a new table in the db from scratch with utf8_unicode_ci collation, inserted there the value in question (ООО "СитиСтрой") and tried these two queries from phpmyadmin:

```
SELECT `company`.`id`, `company`.`company` FROM `company` WHERE (`company`.`id` = 0 AND `company`.`company` REGEXP 'с')
SELECT `company`.`id`, `company`.`company` FROM `company` WHERE (`company`.`id` = 0 AND `company`.`company` REGEXP 'С')
```

Second one works, first one does not.
Really weird.

**update2**
My initial code that formed the query looked like that:

```
query_ka_name = reduce(operator.and_,
(Q(company__iregex=r'(([^\w]|^){i}([^\w]|$))'.format(i=re.sub(r'и|й', '(и|й)', item, flags=re.IGNORECASE)))
```

the purpose of that being to check if a db record corresponded to the array of keywords recognized from a scan as a company name. Since the scanner is really bad with differentiating й from и, and db records are beyond my control I added that little thing to consider these letters as one.

Now the code looks like that:

```
query_ka_name = reduce(operator.and_, (Q(company__iregex=tambourine(item)) for item in ka_name_listed))

def tambourine(string):
    string = re.sub(r'и|й', '(и|й)', string, flags=re.IGNORECASE)
    output = ''
    for char in string:
        if char.isalpha():
            output = '{o}({u}|{l})'.format(o=output, u=char.upper(), l=char.lower())
        else:
            output = '{o}{c}'.format(o=output, c=char)
    output = r'(([^\w]|^){i}([^\w]|$))'.format(i=output)
    return output
```

that is probably slow as hell in comparison, but at least it works. 
Would still greatly appreciate a solution to the problem.

Comment: isn't __iregex supposed to be case insensitive already? as compared to __regex? works with latin at least.

Comment: What [collation settings](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/databases/#collation-settings) are you using?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew your variant returns error btw: Error in formatting: OperationalError: (1139, "Got error 'repetition-operator operand invalid' from regexp")

Comment: @Alasdair the db is using utf8_general_ci

Comment: @Alasdair I tried switching to utf8_unicode_ci becase it is stated as more accurate, but with no avail.

Comment: How did you switch the collation? Are you sure you did that correctly? I don't have any other suggestions I'm afraid.

Comment: @Alasdair went to phpmyadmin interface and changed it at db operations page. Let me know if that way is wrong, and thanks anyway.

Comment: the funny thing is, code like 
re.finditer(p['pattern'], l, flags=re.IGNORECASE) does work. I'll try to use the functions with re.IGNORECASE flag for now I guess, but losing __iregex function is pain.

Comment: Have you tried `u'ситистро(и|й)'`? Or is it Py3? Are you sure all the files are in UTF8?

Comment: @AndreyShipilov tried both u'' and r'' strings, same effect. And yes, it is Python 3.  The .py file with the code has #!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- on top, if that is what you mean.

Comment: Weird. Can you test on a newly created DB with utf8_unicode_ci collation from scratch?

Comment: @AndreyShipilov please see the update in the main post. Time to unpack my tambourine I guess.

Answer (score 1):

- "LATIN SMALL LETTER C is not considered to be the same as "CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER ES".
- Ditto for "CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER I" and "CYRILLIC SMALL LETTER SHORT I"
- MySQL's `REGEXP` works with *bytes* not *characters*.  hence only unaccented English letters work in `REGEXP`; no Cyrillic letter can (reliably) work.
- MariaDB 10.0.5's `REGEXP` should do a better job.  Ref: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/pcre/

Comment: so basically it still comes to switching to another db. Pretty sad. Thanks for the answer, at least I'm not in complete darkness now.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest switching to Postgres database which handles non-latin symbols pretty good.

Just tried to reproduce your issue on my Django 1.10 and Postgres 9.6 setup.

`from django.contrib.auth.models import User
users = User.objects.filter(username__iregex='Сосницки(и|й)')
users
<QuerySet [<User: Сосницкий>, <User: сосницкий>, <User: сосницкии>, <User: СоСницкии>]>`

Seems to be working.